# Scrapy extract different number of column

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, data-extraction

I'm trying to extract value from this HTML file using scrapy:

```
<div class="property-secondary-vl__detail">
        <div class="row">
                                                <div class="property-secondary-vl__detail__column">
                        <div class="property-secondary-vl__detail__key">
                            Tipe Properti                        </div>
                        <div class="property-secondary-vl__detail__value">
                            Rumah                        </div>
                    </div>
                                                                <div class="property-secondary-vl__detail__column">
                        <div class="property-secondary-vl__detail__key">
                            Tipe Iklan                        </div>
                        <div class="property-secondary-vl__detail__value">
                            Dijual                        </div>
                    </div>
                                                                <div class="property-secondary-vl__detail__column">
                        <div class="property-secondary-vl__detail__key">
                            Tipe Market                        </div>
                        <div class="property-secondary-vl__detail__value">
                            Secondary                        </div>
                    </div>
                                                                <div class="property-secondary-vl__detail__column">
                        <div class="property-secondary-vl__detail__key">
                            Umur Bangunan                        </div>
                        <div class="property-secondary-vl__detail__value">
                            Lama                        </div>
                    </div>
                                                                <div class="property-secondary-vl__detail__column">
                        <div class="property-secondary-vl__detail__key">
                            Harga                        </div>
                        <div class="property-secondary-vl__detail__value">
                            Rp1.800.000.000                        </div>
                    </div>
                                                                <div class="property-secondary-vl__detail__column">
                        <div class="property-secondary-vl__detail__key">
                            Sertifikasi                        </div>
                        <div class="property-secondary-vl__detail__value">
                            SHM                        </div>
                    </div>
                                                                <div class="property-secondary-vl__detail__column">
                        <div class="property-secondary-vl__detail__key">
                            Kamar Tidur                        </div>
                        <div class="property-secondary-vl__detail__value">
                            3                        </div>
                    </div>
                                                                <div class="property-secondary-vl__detail__column">
                        <div class="property-secondary-vl__detail__key">
                            Kamar Mandi                        </div>
                        <div class="property-secondary-vl__detail__value">
                            3                        </div>
                    </div>
                                                                <div class="property-secondary-vl__detail__column">
                        <div class="property-secondary-vl__detail__key">
                            Luas Tanah                        </div>
                        <div class="property-secondary-vl__detail__value">
                            104m²                        </div>
                    </div>
                                                                <div class="property-secondary-vl__detail__column">
                        <div class="property-secondary-vl__detail__key">
                            Luas Bangunan                        </div>
                        <div class="property-secondary-vl__detail__value">
                            125m²                        </div>
                    </div>
                                                                <div class="property-secondary-vl__detail__column">
                        <div class="property-secondary-vl__detail__key">
                            Jumlah Lantai                        </div>
                        <div class="property-secondary-vl__detail__value">
                            3                        </div>
                    </div>
                                                                <div class="property-secondary-vl__detail__column">
                        <div class="property-secondary-vl__detail__key">
                            Carports                        </div>
                        <div class="property-secondary-vl__detail__value">
                            2                        </div>
                    </div>
                                                                <div class="property-secondary-vl__detail__column">
                        <div class="property-secondary-vl__detail__key">
                            Daya Listrik                        </div>
                        <div class="property-secondary-vl__detail__value">
                            5500 watt                        </div>
                    </div>
                                                                <div class="property-secondary-vl__detail__column">
                        <div class="property-secondary-vl__detail__key">
                            Interior                        </div>
                        <div class="property-secondary-vl__detail__value">
                            Semi Furnished                        </div>
                    </div>
                                                                <div class="property-secondary-vl__detail__column">
                        <div class="property-secondary-vl__detail__key">
                            Tahun Dibangun                        </div>
                        <div class="property-secondary-vl__detail__value">
                            2005                        </div>
                    </div>
                                    </div>
    </div>
```

I want the "__detail__key" as a column header while the "__detail__value" is the value itself.

the other problem is, on this particular property listing website, every listing has a different number of items.

example:
on this listing https://www.99.co/id/properti/rumah-dijual-1-8mily-ciputat-timur-520409782, there is 15 column on "__detail__key", while in this listing https://www.99.co/id/properti/rumah-dijual-1-65mily-pamulang-410793202 there are 16 columns.

Is it possible to do this using scrapy?

Comment: Have you tried ```.getall()``` then looping through the lists?

Comment: can you explain in more detail? I'm still a newbie on this matter